# Add a Check if ExternalEmailAddress already exists in the CSV and if it does do nothing

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

How would I do this? Any ideas? I just want to make sure my script does not try to create a new mailContact if the ExternalEmailAddress already exists.

```
If (Test-Path $CSVFileName) {

    #Import the CSV file
    $csvfile = Import-CSV $CSVFileName
        
    #Loop through CSV file
    foreach ($line in $csvfile) {

        try {
            #Create the mail contact    
            New-MailContact -domaincontroller $dc -Name $line.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $line.ExternalEmailAddress  -OrganizationalUnit $OU -ErrorAction STOP
            Set-Contact -domaincontroller $dc -Identity $line.Name -Department $line.Department -Title "Sales Team" -StreetAddress $line.StreetAddress -City $line.City -StateOrProvince $line.StateOrProvince -PostalCode $line.PostalCode -Office $line.Office -CountryOrRegion $line.CountryOrRegion
            "$($line.Name) was created successfully." | Out-File $logfile -Append
        }
        catch {
            
            $message = "A problem occured trying to create the $($line.Name) contact"
            $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
            Write-Warning $message
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
            $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing any fundamental issue with your approach.  If you are worried about testing it, create a  truncated version of the CSV file, to see how the script reacts with some tests accounts or whatnot.  You could also make use of the `-WhatIf` parameter on the `New` & `Set` commands to check which objects will be affected, but without making the change.

I have to assume the `$OU` variable is defined elsewhere.  The only other thing I'd suggest is to use splatting to make it more readable.  That might look something like this:

```
$NewParams = @{
   DomainController     = $dc
   OrganizationalUnit   = $OU
   ErrorAction          = 'Stop'
}

$SetParams = @{
   DomainController = $dc      
   Title            = 'Sales Team'      
}

If (Test-Path $CSVFileName) {

   #Import the CSV file
   $csvfile = Import-CSV $CSVFileName
   
   # Adjust splatting hash tables per incoming line:
   $NewParams['Name']                 = $line.Name
   $NewParams['ExternalEmailAddress'] = $line.ExternalEmailAddress

   # Adjust splatting hash for the set command:
   $SetParams['Identity']             = $line.Name
   $SetParams['Department']           = $line.Department
   $SetParams['StreetAddress']        = $line.StreetAddress
   $SetParams['City']                 = $line.City
   $SetParams['StateOrProvince']      = $line.StateOrProvince
   $SetParams['PostalCode']           = $line.PostalCode
   $SetParams['Office']               = $line.Office
   $SetParams['CountryOrRegion']      = $line.CountryOrRegion

   #Loop through CSV file
   foreach ($line in $csvfile) {

       try {
           #Create the mail contact    
           New-MailContact @NewParams
           Set-Contact @SetParams
           "$($line.Name) was created successfully." | Out-File $logfile -Append
       }
       catch {
           
           $message = "A problem occured trying to create the $($line.Name) contact"
           $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
           Write-Warning $message
           Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
           $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
       }

   }
}
```

This example sets up 2 hash tables with constant values. Then inside the loop, it will add and/or change the variable parameters in the hashes, per line of input.  They simply reference those hashes as the argument to the `New-MailContact` & `Set-Contact` commands.

The Exchange Management Shell will not let you duplicate an SMTP address. If you attempt to it will return an error like:

```
The proxy address "SMTP:Example@Example.com" is already being used by the proxy addresses or LegacyExchangeDN of "local.domian/Users/OtheMailEnabledObject". Please choose another proxy address.
```

However, if you want to prevent errors altogether and/or prevent writing these specific kinds of errors to the log there are a few things you can do.

From a code perspective, the easiest thing to do is to simply add an If block with a `Get-Recipient` command.

```
#...
    #Loop through CSV file
    foreach ($line in $csvfile) {
        If( !(Get-Recipient $line.ExternalEmailAddress) ) {
            try {
                #Create the mail contact    
                New-MailContact @NewParams
                Set-Contact @SetParams
                "$($line.Name) was created successfully." | Out-File $logfile -Append
            }
            catch {            
                $message = "A problem occured trying to create the $($line.Name) contact"
                $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
                Write-Warning $message
                Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
                $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: `Get-Recipient` is more thorough than `Get-MailContact`.

Another approach might be to simply handle those specific errors differently.

```
#...
    #Loop through CSV file
    foreach ($line in $csvfile) {
        try {
            #Create the mail contact    
            New-MailContact @NewParams
            Set-Contact @SetParams
            "$($line.Name) was created successfully." | Out-File $logfile -Append
        }
        catch {
            If( $Error[0].CategoryInfo.Reason -ne 'ProxyAddressExistsException' ){
                $message = "A problem occured trying to create the $($line.Name) contact"
                $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
                Write-Warning $message
                Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
                $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
            }
        }
    }
```

So in this case you are only logging when the error **isn't** a duplicate proxy address.  You can of course create additional logic depending on what you want.

If you have a very large number of contacts to create both of these methods might be rather slow.  This is because they'd be executing a lot of commands they don't need to.  For the latter approach, the performance hit would be related to how many duplicate errors actually occur. For the former, you'd take a hit on each loop iteration because you're always checking regardless of whether the `New-MailContact` command will be successful anyway.

So the last approach is to create a list of existing proxy addresses you can check against before trying to create a new contact.

To compile a list of all SMTP proxy addresses:

```
$ExistingAddresses = 
Get-Recipient ResultSize Unlimited | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses | 
Where-Object{$_.PrefixString -eq 'SMTP'} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty SmtpAddress
```

However, `Get-Recipient` may have problems paging through large sets returned by a large query.  Depends on your environment.  If you do have a problem you can use an alternate approach using AD cmdlets, which will be much faster in any case.

```
$ExistingAddresses =
Get-ADObject -Filter "mailnickname -like '*'" -Properties 'ProxyAddresses' |
 ForEach-Object{ 
    ForEach($ProxyAddress in $_.ProxyAddresses)
    {
        If( $ProxyAddress -match "^smtp" ) {
            $ProxyAddress.Split(':')[1]
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have `$ExistingAddresses` populated you can change the loop to check the list first:

```
foreach ($line in $csvfile) {
    If( $line.ExternalEmailAddress -notin $ExistingAddresses ) {
        try {
            #Create the mail contact    
            New-MailContact @NewParams
            Set-Contact @SetParams
            "$($line.Name) was created successfully." | Out-File $logfile -Append
        }
        catch {
            $message = "A problem occured trying to create the $($line.Name) contact"
            $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
            Write-Warning $message
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
            $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
        }
    }
}
```

Again, you can build additional logic if desired.  For example, an `Else{...}` if you want to report finding a duplicate etc...

Based on additional comments. If you want to run a set command on those contacts that already existed.  here's 1 example:

```
#Loop through CSV file
foreach ($line in $csvfile) {
    If( !(Get-Recipient $line.ExternalEmailAddress) ) {
        try {
            #Create the mail contact    
            New-MailContact @NewParams
            "$($line.Name) was created successfully." | Out-File $logfile -Append
        }
        catch {            
            $message = "A problem occured trying to create the $($line.Name) contact"
            $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
            Write-Warning $message
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
            $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
        }
    }
    # The contact either already exists or was just created, so long as you
    # Use the same domain controller go ahead and perform the Set...
    Set-Contact @SetParams
}
```

Again, there are a thousand ways to arrange something like this.  And, all of the above approaches can probably be modified to satisfy the new requirement.  However, this will not tell you which properties get updated. If you want that kind of property level comparison, we'd have to write still more code.

Comment: Steven, How would I add a If Statement in your code above, to check if the ExternalEmailAddress is already there?

Comment: In my view, you don't need to do that.  ESM will not let you duplicate an address and the error it generates will get caught. I suppose it's always wise to prevent an error than to rely on catching it, so I'll update with some examples.

Comment: Updated to cover everything you need.  If you are comfortable please accept the answer. Either way, let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Your example does the trick, however what if I want to check if a contact has been modified?

Comment: and if it has been modified update the field.

Comment: What do you mean, if it does exist you want to ensure the other properties are correct regardless?  And, if so it matters if you want to report or otherwise log what's changing. Between the above approaches, I think you have everything you need. You may need to work on the logic.  What does "has been modified" mean?  That the data in the CSV is different than the data in an existing contact?

Comment: Correct. If it exists, ensure the properties are correct according to the CSV. By Modified I just mean if any of fields have been changed.

Comment: I added an example that will set the properties on a preexisting contact.  However, to go any further would mean writing functionality to compare property by property,  Don't get me wrong, all can be done, but we are certainly off scope from the question.

Comment: I will create another question.